# Why is my PHP E-mail form attracting spam?

Tags: php, forms, email, captcha, spam

I have built a website and I want to have an e-mail contact form on the web page, so that someone can send me a message.

I am using the code from this website: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_secure_mail.asp

I am using the part that says **PHP Stopping E-mail Injections**

Even though my site gets very few hits per day (like less than 10 visitors) I am finding that I am getting 3 or 4 messages every day from "spammers" who just seem to be sending me random messages that are not related to the subject matter of the website.

I am fairly new to all this, so I would like to ask the question: **Why is my PHP e-mail form attracting Spam and what can I do to stop it?**

Ideally I would like to make it as easy as possible for the real users to contact me, and I would prefer it if I didn't have to use a CAPTCHA if possible.

Thanks so much

Code I am using:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else
    {//send email
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("someone@example.com", "Subject: $subject",
    $message, "From: $email" );
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
  }
else
  {//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: use CAPTCHA its best option... also, what about real spammer? real person that submits the form? in this case, there will be no way to prevent it

Comment: Without some form of human verification (i.e. CAPTCHA, Q&A, etc.) you can't circumvent this. You could try hooking into Akismet or something similar too.

Comment: if you're taking your advice from w3schools, then you're not taking very good advice. They're not the best source to go to, and the code you've given above bears that out -- the "spam check" function is nothing of the sort; it just validates that the email address is valid; it does nothing to prevent them sending you spam. The sanitize is useful, but wouldn't be necessary if you were using a decent mailer class like [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/), instead of PHP's built-in `mail()` function (which frankly is pretty poor and easily hacked).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a simple way to get rid of most spammers:

output an input field inside your form that as `display: none;` as a style. Ideally that is specified in an external css file.

Put that input field inside your form and give it an important name, like "name2" or something.

Then, when eveluating input, discard all  requests that have avalue inside that field, as a real user can not see and and thus can't enter a value. Whereas spam bots most likely fill all fields they find on a page.

Comment: it's called a honey pot - works really well, you can add other things in to check how fast the form is filled in (a robot if it's under say 5 seconds) and us a points based system.  But the honeypot by itself works really well.

Comment: Thanks for the honey pot comment. I only knew the term from virus reseach (the digital ones ;) )