# PHP Email sign-up emails going to spam folder

Tags: php

first time post. I did read through the site on this question but I didn't find the answer or didn't realize I found the answer. I'm putting a simple PHP email sign-up box on a web site. Here is my code:

`enter code here`

```
 function spamcheck($field)
   {
   $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
   return FALSE;
   }
   }

    $recipient = "mymail@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Email subscription list";
    $sender = $recipient;
    $subscription = $_REQUEST['subscription']; 

    if (isset($_REQUEST['emaillist']))
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['emaillist']);
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
   else
    {

    $body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['emaillist']." \n";
    $body .= "Subscribe: ".$_REQUEST['subscription']." \n";

    if ($subscription == "subscribe")
    {$location = "thankyou.html";}
    else {$location = "thankyou2.html";};

    mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be   sent.");
    header( "Location: $location" ); } ?>
```

The emails go to the spam folder using either my gmail or an email on the site's domain. I think it's because the subject and recipient are the same, but it could simply be a matter of telling our site host to allow these mails through. Any help/suggestions are appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636993/why-is-my-php-e-mail-form-attracting-spam?rq=1

Comment: you're emailing yourself? just tell the mail client to allow these emails.

Answer (score 0):

> $sender = $recipient;

Since you are sending an email to yourself, create a filter to prevent mails from yourself going into spam. Creating filters is explained [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-email-filters-gmail-hotmail-yahoo/)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question everyone but thanks for responding.